# Is a Singleton Apache Thrift client better than multiple client instances?

Tags: c#, client-server, thrift

I have a thrift server app and another client app that communicates with it through apache thrift.

3 questions:

1 - In my client app, when creating a thrift client and opening the transport for communication, is it better to reuse the same client and transport as a singleton for the whole application lifetime (aka always on), by keeping the transport opened, or it would be better to create a new client, open the transport, then close it when done on each call to the thrift server?

2 - Why?

3 - In terms of performance, does it change anything (considering the overhead of opening and closing the transport and data throughput through the same client)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'1 & '2. A single Thrift client w/ I/O stack (proto/trans) represents a single connection. Connections are relatively expensive to setup and tear down so if you use the client regularly, keeping it around is usually a good idea. However, client objects are not usually thread safe, so if your application is multithreaded you will need to manage access to the client so that RPC request/response operations are serialized.

'3. If you make RPC requests often, opening and closing connections will add a lot of overhead, so usually best to keep the connection open. On the other hand if you rarely make RPC requests, holding the connection open will tie up resources on the server when you are not using them, so best to open and close for each sparse request.

My advise in a vacuum is to create a single client per independent thread but the real answer is to experiment with each case and measure the results, choosing the fastest/least expensive outcome.

Comment: Shouldn't we keep thrift client pool as it is mentioned here : https://layer4.fr/blog/2013/11/04/pooling-a-thrift-client/ ? I think that will be good idea to keep a client pool in case of multithreaded environment.

Comment: If you make rare requests, pooling will not reduce load on the server. If you make frequent requests on all threads, swapping clients in and out of a pool will slow the client down. If you make frequent requests distributed across a set of threads but no one thread is a heavy user a pool may be a good option. The only way to know the right answer for your application is to measure it under actual load in each model.

Comment: what do you mean by connection? is it transport or socket?

Comment: I am assuming the question refers to a TSocket based transport connection. "Sockets" are an abstraction, in this case, representing a connectable end point. The TSocket transport in Apache Thrift uses a TCP connection to make RPC requests. Each connection incurs operating system overhead, so the goal is to balance the OS overhead with the application use pattern. Considerations for THttp and TNamedPipes connections would also be similar, though the pool/no-pool and connection persistence break points might differ.